# how to access to a sub-set of a dictionary through a sub-set of a key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For efficiency reason, I am representing a textual huge dictionary as a Python dictionary with a key in form of a tuple `(first letter, number of letter)`. We can visualize it as a matrix. Let us have an example built from a list:

```
l=["baby", "bird","as","at", "friend","always"]
d = {}
for mot in l:
  if (len(mot), mot[0]) in d:
      d[len(mot),mot[0]].append(mot)
  else:
      d[len(mot),mot[0]] = [mot]

print("d : ", d)
```

The result is:

```
d :  {(6, 'a'): ['always'], (6, 'f'): ['friend'], (2, 'a'): ['as', 'at'], (4, 'b'): ['baby', 'bird']}
```

The question is how to print/access to a line or a row in a single command.
For example: all the words starting with a, or all the words of length 6.

Comment: The *real* question is, can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: The short answer is: you can't. That's not how dictionaries work. You could have to search through all keys, check what they contain and concatenate the results.

Comment: I wonder if there is a better collection you can use, instead of a dictionary with a tuple as a key.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Does a list comprehension count as a "single command"? :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat it does but, given that the OP is concerned about efficiency, trawling in `O(n)` through all key-value pairs doesn't make the most of hash-based lookups.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiency" reason?  What problem are you trying to solve?  Using a tuple as a key is *not* efficient, as you will need to loop over *all* of them to find the one(s) you want.

Answer (score 2):

use filter builtin, it takes two argument, function and iterable:

```
filter(lambda x, y: x[0] == 6, d.items())
```

Answer (score 2):

With a single command, one option could be:

```
lines = [d[k] for k in d if k[1] == 'a']
```

similarly for the other case.

But, this totally beats the point of using a dictionary, now you've just scanned over all the keys to find elements that partially share the key.

It would be more efficient, time-wise, to relate each length with a dictionary of letters and do a double key-lookup; this obviously increases the memory requirements of the structure but that's the trade-off you need to pay.

Comment: Yes your solution is good but I do not agree with the comment: scanning all the keys is not too expensive for a dictionary (through 26 letters or 1 to 15 length). In this condition, finding a word or correcting word spelling could be efficient. What do you think of this remark?

Comment: @Hana: Let's say you have entries for all 26 letters between 1 and 15 letters long.  Then you'll have `(1, 'a')` all the way to `(15, 'z')`, that's 390 keys that you'll need to *loop* through every single time.  It'd be faster to have a way to just look up the length/letter in its own dictionary/collection... I think.

Comment: 390 keys is not too much for a dictionnary of more than 100000 words.Could you give me more details about a double key-lookup principle;

Comment: @Hana you can nest the dictionaries, choosing a length as the first key and a letter as the second: `{6: {'a': [...], 'b': [...], ...}, 5: {'a': [...], ...}...}`. After that, looking for your rows would involve doing `d[6]['a']` which is a very fast operation.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard The idea is good. Can't we improve access to words by sub-dictionnary: How to represent the list (last level) by a dictionnary {'"word1":true, "word2":true, ...}  to have a more efficent access (hash-code) to the existence or not of a word.

Comment: @Hana you can use a `set` for that, `set`s are perfect for membership tests (By using `'word' in d[6]['a']`, you'd be doing `O(1)` operations all the way.) A dict would do the same job but the sets handles that case better.